# Simple ByteBuffer FIFO Stack

Tags: android, bytebuffer

I have a ByteBuffer of fixed length and want to 'unshift' a byte (or bytes) to the beginning of the buffer, whilst simultaneously 'popping' bytes from the end of the buffer, i.e., pretty much like streaming data through a fixed length buffer. The bytes popped of the back are just deleted.

I'm new to all this buffering, and confused as to the best way to achieve this (performance is key). Is it best to use the `ByteBuffer`'s `slice()` and `put` commands.? For example, to 'unshift' and 'pop' a byte, one could do something like:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = getMyBuffer();

buffer.position(0);
buffer.limit(buffer.capacity() - 1);
ByteBuffer slicedBuffer = buffer.slice();

buffer.position(0);
buffer.put(newByte);
buffer.put(slicedBuffer);
```

Is this usually how this is done? Or being a noob am I missing something obvious? Thanks.